# Magento - Disable redirect

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, seo

What's the best way to deal with the following redirect:

You enter website.com/category you get redirected to https://website.com/category, then to https://website.com/category.html

I want to eliminate/reduce the number of redirect to speed up the page load time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove that .html or redirection . open catalog under catalog sidebar in configuration page ->search engine optimization and remove product URL suffix and category url suffix in pic below remove the .html value with blank.

[image]